# Is it possible to capture audio output and apply effects to it?

Tags: .net, audio, directx

Using .NET and DirectSound I want to be able to take **all output** sound that is coming from my audio device and apply effects to it. I've had a quick look at the docs on MSDN and there doesn't seem to be any explanation as to how to do something like this.

I've read elsewhere that you'd be better off writing a driver to sit in front of your real audio driver and have that do whatever you want with the sound.

Any ideas anyone to push me in the right direction?

Edit:

After a bit more research it looks like the Windows SDK provides a bit of functionality for this sort of thing. Can anyone confirm/deny?

Comment: You want to apply DSP efects to everthing that's being outputed by your sound card, no matter what application it originated from?

Comment: Yes - sort of like a replacement for the Windows Mixer but with a couple of bells and whistles added on

Comment: **working** example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609469/cscore-how-to-apply-an-effect-during-audio-capture

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

**Audio DSP with C#**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/audio_process.aspx

Comment: Doesn't look like that does what I'm looking for. Looks pretty useful otherwise though. Thanks